# Descobrir id de objeto clicado

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma mini loja virtual, e a minha dificuldade esta sendo recuperar o id do objeto clicado, para quando clicar no item, seja carregada outra pagina com as informaçoes do objeto clicado. No caso a variavel **a** na função abrirItem é que vai receber o id:

```
    var item = [
        {
            id: '0',
            produto: 'Camisa branca',
            img: 'imagens/camisabranca.jpg',
            quantidade: '0',
            valor: 'R$ 100'  
            
        },

        {
            id: '1',
            produto: 'Camisa preta',
            img: "imagens/camisapreta.jpg",
            quantidade: '0',
            valor: 'R$ 120'
        },

        {
            id: '2',
            produto: 'Camisa azul',
            img: 'imagens/camisaazul.jpg',
            quantidade: '0',
            valor: 'R$ 150'
        },
    ]

    

    inicializarLoja = () => {
      
       var novaDiv = document.createElement('div')
       for(let i = 0; i<item.length; i++)
       
       novaDiv.innerHTML += `
       <a onclick ="abrirItem()" id="" href="produto.html" class="item">
            
            <p class = "titulo">${item[i].produto}</p>
            <img style="width: 100px; height:117px;" src = "${item[i].img}">
            <span> ${item[i].valor} </span>
        </a>
       `
        novaDiv.className = 'nova'
        
        document.body.appendChild(novaDiv)
        console.log(novaDiv.id)
    }

   
    abrirItem = () => {
    window.open =  "produto.html" 
    let a = 0
        
    let novoItem = document.createElement('div')
        
    novoItem.innerHTML = `
       <div >
            
            <p class = "titulo">${item[a].produto}</p>
            <img style="width: 100px; height:117px;" src = "${item[a].img}">
            <span> ${item[a].valor} </span>
        </div>
       `
        novoItem.className = 'novo'
        document.body.appendChild(novoItem)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basta passar uma referência do elemento como parâmetro utilizando o `this`. Um exemplo simplificado da utilização é o seguinte:

```js
const clicar = (id) => {
  console.log(`Elemento ${id} foi clicado`);
};
```

```html
<button id="botao1" onclick="clicar(this.id)">Teste</button>
```